# How do I access fetch data from an array of promises when using promise.all in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to access data from the restcountries.eu API using a `promise.all` but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
function displayCurrency(currencyone, currencytwo) {
    
    Promise.all([
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencyone}`),
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencytwo}`)
    ])
        .then(function (responses) {
            return responses.map(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            });
        }).then(function (data) {
          
            console.log(data[0]);


        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

`data[0]` displays a resolved promise with an array. I try to access data in the array such as 'name' and 'currencies' but I just keep getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mapping, you're creating an array of `.json()` calls - an array of Promises. You'd need to call `Promise.all` on it again.

```js
// Not actually runnable, just hidden by default;
// this is very inelegant, use the other method instead

function displayCurrency(currencyone, currencytwo) {
    const arrOfJsonProms = Promise.all([
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencyone}`),
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencytwo}`)
    ])
        .then(function (responses) {
            return responses.map(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
        });
    Promise.all(arrOfJsonProms)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

But it would be more elegant to call `.json` inside the initial `Promise.all`, that way the code is simpler *and* you don't have to wait for every connection to initialize before downloading a body:

```
function displayCurrency(currencyone, currencytwo) {
    Promise.all([
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencyone}`).then(res => res.json()),
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencytwo}`).then(res => res.json())
    ])
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), something like the following:

```js
const displayCurrency = async (currencyone, currencytwo) => {
  try {
    let responses = await Promise.all([
      fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencyone}`),
      fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${currencytwo}`),
    ]);
    let data = await Promise.all(
      responses.map(async (response) => await response.json())
    );
    console.log(data[0]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

displayCurrency("eur", "aud");
```